# Type of neural network to use to classify continuous data in two different states

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

A general question: I have continuous data on animal records, measured at roughly 30-day intervals. I would like to classify the records in different states (e.g. animal does not have disease and then later the animal does). How do I treat the records as repeated measurements in a neural network?

I have tried before to treat each record independently, therefore the network does not now that it is repeated records. The network can predict (to some extent) a specific state of each record, but I want to know how an animal changed over time. Would this be a LSTM network?

I have used dense feed forward networks, as well as convolutional networks, but don't know how to use repeated records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Julio. Additionally, you can allow your dense feed forward networks to consider the temporal dependencies of your data by feeding it a window of your features. Moreover, add shifted version of your features as additional features to train on.

Usually this type of architecture performs well with simple time series problems and can be treated as a baseline model to LSTM. It is useful to try simple models before looking into complicated and computationally expensive models such as RNNs. Being said, any real advantages you get from any further complication in your model is genuine.

Here is a simple function that can generate a sliding window of your time series:

```
def generator(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
              shuffle=False, batch_size=128, step=6):
    if max_index is None:
        max_index = len(data) - delay - 1
    i = min_index + lookback
    while 1:
        if shuffle:
            rows = np.random.randint(
                min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size)
        else:
            if i + batch_size >= max_index:
                i = min_index + lookback
            rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
            i += len(rows)

        samples = np.zeros((len(rows),
                           lookback // step,
                           data.shape[-1]))
        targets = np.zeros((len(rows),))
        for j, row in enumerate(rows):
            indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j], step)
            samples[j] = data[indices]
            targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay][1]
        yield samples, targets
```

This code is taken from `Deep learning in Python`'s [Notebook](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/6.3-advanced-usage-of-recurrent-neural-networks.ipynb)

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you. I’ll lookup some more on this topic and start testing it out. Thank you!

Comment: Hope you got somewhere with my answer, if you think my answer was helpful to you, then you can upvote it or mark it as an answer. Otherwise, let me know if you need any further help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a RNN may work, you can use many to one or a many to many model.

I recommend you to read:

- [The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Recurrent Neural Networks](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/) by Andrej Karpathy
- [Understanding LSTM Networks](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) by Christopher Olah